# Convert tiff to png or jpg image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minimagick

I am trying to save an image with format tiff. It is getting saved but the problem is tiff format is not compatible with all browser so I need to convert the image while saving it. I am using carrier wave and mini-magick. Whenever I try to save tiff image I am getting this error Attachment .
   **translation missing: en.errors.messages.mini_magick_processing_error**

**Attachment Uploader**

```
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

    version :normal do
    process :mogrify => [{
      :resolution => '108x369'
    }]
  end

  def default_url
    "#{model.class.to_s.underscore.downcase}/#{mounted_as}/missing/" + [version_name, 'missing.png'].compact.join('_')
  end

 def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png bmp tif tiff)
  end

  def filename
    "#{model.nicely_formatted_filename}.png"
  end

private

  def mogrify(options = {})
    manipulate! do |img|

      img.format("png") do |c|
        c.fuzz        "3%"
        c.trim
        c.rotate      "#{options[:rotate]}" if options.has_key?(:rotate)
        c.resize      "#{options[:resolution]}>" if options.has_key?(:resolution)
        c.resize      "#{options[:resolution]}<" if options.has_key?(:resolution)
        c.profile.+   "!xmp,*"
        c.profile     "#{Rails.root}/lib/color_profiles/sRGB_v4_ICC_preference_displayclass.icc"
        c.colorspace  "sRGB"
      end
      img
    end
  end

end
```

**Log**

```
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`
Processing by ResumesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"STirkPS7rf8aHuvAhLrW/06tL+psjaxXZMfFiuja5mEmInq1Pzf0EZxjE1r66vC9eLE64jUDC+AnvzYb1r4wGQ==", "resume"=>{"name"=>"asas", "attachment"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000002c509e8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170912-27107-9zr3ju.tiff>, @original_filename="relayOutputMessageSmall.tiff", @content_type="image/tiff", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"resume[attachment]\"; filename=\"relayOutputMessageSmall.tiff\"\r\nContent-Type: image/tiff\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Save"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered resumes/new.html.erb within layouts/application (12.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 354ms (Views: 275.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
```

Comment: DId you have a look into your logs? Your development.log should have some output from mini_magick, I guess?

Comment: yeah, it is getting roll back but could not figure it out.I am updating my answer with logs

Comment: You're probably missing the necessary `imagemagick` library to manipulate the file. For example, on mac you can: `brew install imagemagick`.

Comment: The error translation should be getting picked up from [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/c2ee2e89d3aa447c6b81186be6d627202d33a97f/lib/carrierwave/locale/en.yml#L11) -- If you're defining them locally instead, you'll need to update that file.

Comment: I have imagemagick install on my system .Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2017-07-31 http://www.imagemagick.org

Comment: Try to "upload" a file via `rails console`. It will (hopefully) show a more meaningful error message.

Comment: (Regarding "not defining translations locally", you can add `gem 'carrierwave-i18n'` to use the built-in translation)